# Powershell implicitly converting arrays preventing use with Select -Property in v2

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-2.0, implicit-conversion, return-type

I am struggling with powershell implicitly modifying the structure of the data in **powershell 2 exclusively**. The same logic works fine in powershell 4.

I've created a helper function that given a field, an alias and/or a block expression i can then feed this into a second function that builds a name/expression array which can be passed to a Select -Property request. this worked fine in powershell 4 however i'm working in a mixed environment and when i tried to use it on a powershell 2 server the script failed returning a datatype conversion error.

```
Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCo    mmand
+ PSComputerName        : ####
```

i now have to basically rebuild the array in the calling function because even an explicit conversion to array raises the same exception.

```
if ($PSVersionTable["PSVersion"].Major -eq 2)
{
    #write-host "rebuilding setting"
    $origprops = [System.Array](Get-SelectPropertyArray2 $propsToSelect)
    $props = @()
    for ($i =0 ; $i -lt $origprops.Count ; $i++)
    {
        #write-host $i
        $props += @{n=([System.Array]$origprops)[$i]["n"];e=(([System.Array]$origprops)[$i]["e"])}
    }
}
```

The following is insufficient:

```
[System.Array](Get-SelectPropertyArray2 $propsToSelect)
```

When i do a GetType() at initialization, addition to array and return statements the Type is always System.Object, System.Array

However in the calling function it is becomes System.HashTable

Here is an example of using the function:

```
$propsToSelect = @("Name","Path","PSPath")
# Get-SelectPropertyArraySet takes a field to return, an alias and an optional code block (to override the default)
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_AppAllowClientDebug" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp -Name AppAllowClientDebug -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_AppAllowDebugging" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp -Name AppAllowDebugging -PSPath $PSPath).Value }

$props = (Get-SelectPropertyArray2 $propsToSelect)
# the following line is the one that fails
$config = Get-Item $PSPath | select -Property $props
```

**the following line is the one that fails** unless i rebuild the array as shown above.

```
$config = Get-Item $PSPath | select -Property $props
```

When i write out the types, i get the following results:

```
PS C:\scripts\ps\bits> $p = Get-SelectPropertyArray2 $set
init:

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


Inc Alias:

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


return:

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\scripts\ps\bits> $p.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

As you can see the last one is quite different, if i then use this on my select statement it will fail with the exception shown previously.

Here are the functions code:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Generates a PSObject with a Field/Alias/Expression set for use with the Get-SelectPropertyArray2 function.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Generates a PSObject with a Field/Alias/Expression Set for use with the Get-SelectPropertyArray2 function.

    The Alias property is optional

    .EXAMPLE
    Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "Name"

    .EXAMPLE 
    Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AccessFlags" "Access Flags"

    .EXAMPLE 
    Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AccessFlags" "Access Flags"

    .EXAMPLE
    $propsToSelect = @(
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "Name"),
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AccessFlags" "Access Flags"),
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AuthAnonymous" "Auth Anonymous")
                        )

    Get-SelectPropertyArray2  $propsToSelect

    .PARAMETER Field
    [string] Name of the field to select
    .PARAMETER Alias
    [string] Alias Name of the field to select
    .PARAMETER Expression
    [ScriptBlock] Script block to use for capturing the data, allows for custom field definitions outside standard aliasing.

#>
function Get-SelectPropertyArraySet 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("f")]
           [string]$Field,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Alias("a")]
           [string]$Alias,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Alias("e")]
           [ScriptBlock]$Expression
    )
    #Write-Host "Building Property Set for $field, $alias"# with $Expression"
    new-object PSObject -Property @{Field=$field; Alias=$alias; Expression=$expression}
}
```

And the second function (the lines to write out the data types are included but commented out):

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Generates an array of script blocks which can be passed to a select statement. Aliasing the field name.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Generates an array of script blocks which can be passed to a select statement. Aliasing the field name.

    The input is an PSObject with a Field and Alias property

    For Example:
    Field:    Alias:       
    -----------  ------------
    Name         Name
    MyField      MyField Alias

    A helper function Get-SelectPropertyArraySet can be used to create this PSObject.

    .EXAMPLE
    $propsToSelect = @(
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "Name"),
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AccessFlags" "Access Flags"),
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AuthAnonymous" "Auth Anonymous")
                        )
    $propsToSelect | Get-SelectPropertyArray2

    .EXAMPLE
    $propsToSelect = @(
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "Name"),
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AccessFlags" "Access Flags"),
                        (Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AuthAnonymous" "Auth Anonymous")
                        )

    Get-SelectPropertyArray2  $propsToSelect
    .EXAMPLE
    $propsToSelect = @(
                        (new-object PSObject -Property @{Field="Name"}),
                        (new-object PSObject -Property @{Field="AccessFlags"; Alias="Access Flags"}),
                        (new-object PSObject -Property @{Field="AuthAnonymous"; Alias="Auth Anonymous"})
                        )

    Get-SelectPropertyArray2  $propsToSelect




    .PARAMETER PropertiesToSelect
    [PSObject] array containing the Field/Alias pair to use

#>
function Get-SelectPropertyArray2
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Alias("Prop")]
           [PSObject]$PropertiesToSelect
    )
    begin {
        #Initialize property-array for Select-Object
        $PropArray = @()
        #write-host "init"
        #write-host init: 
        #$PropArray.GetType() | out-host

    }
    process {

        #create script block for each field in the input array/pipeline
        #write-host "start"
        #$PropertiesToSelect | select Field,Alias
        foreach ($PropertySet in $PropertiesToSelect)
        {
            $sb = $null
            if ($PropertySet.GetType().Name -eq "String")
            {
                #Write-Host string found
                $fieldName = $PropertySet
                $fieldAlias = $null
            }
            else
            {
                #Write-Host object found
                $fieldName = $PropertySet.Field
                $fieldAlias = $PropertySet.Alias  
                #use provided expression if present and valid type
                if ($PropertySet.Expression)
                {
                    #write-host "Expression Found"
                    #$Propertyset.Expression.GetType().Name
                    switch ($Propertyset.Expression.GetType().Name)
                    {
                        "ScriptBlock"
                        {
                            #Write-Host "Expression is [ScriptBlock]"
                            $sb = $PropertySet.Expression
                        }
                        "String"
                        {
                            #Write-Host "Expression is [String], converting to [ScriptBlock]"

                            $sb = [Scriptblock]::Create($PropertySet.Expression)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            if (! ($sb)) { <#write-host "No SB, using default";#> $sb = [Scriptblock]::Create("`$_.`"$fieldName`"") }

            #"Mapping Field: {0} --> {1}" -f $fieldName,$FieldAlias |Write-Host
            if ($FieldAlias)
            {
                #write-host Inc Alias: 
                #$PropArray.GetType() | out-host
                $PropArray += @{n=[string]$fieldAlias;e=($sb)}
            }
            else #singleton - no alias
            {
                #write-host Inc Field: 
                #$PropArray.GetType()  |out-host
                $PropArray += @{n=[string]$fieldName;e=($sb)}
            }
        }

        # return the script block array
        #Write-Host "end"
        #write-host "<--$PropertiesToSelect"


    }
    end {
        #write-host "return:"
        #write-host return: 
        #$PropArray.GetType() |out-host



        return $PropArray
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace `return $PropArray` to `$PropArray` in `Get-SelectPropertyArray2`.

Comment: That Solved it! Why did that work? From what i read about the about_Return the `$a; return` and `return $a` are the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two differences in V2 vs V4 what related to your issue:

1. Objects returned by `return` statement, get wrapped into `PSObject` in V2:

   ```powershell
   [Type]::GetTypeArray(@(&{return "Name"}))[0].FullName
   ```

   return `System.Management.Automation.PSObject` in V2 and `System.String` in V4.
2. `Select-Object` cmdlet in V2 can not handle wrapped objects for `Property` parameter:

   ```powershell
   Select-Object (,[PSObject]"Name")
   ```

   Error in V2, OK in V4.

**PS:**
Can I ask one thing? What benefits do you have by this:

```powershell
$propsToSelect = @(
    Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "Name"
    Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AccessFlags" "Access Flags"
    Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "AuthAnonymous" "Auth Anonymous"
)
$props = Get-SelectPropertyArray2 $propsToSelect
```

or this:

```powershell
$propsToSelect = @(
    new-object PSObject -Property @{Field="Name"}
    new-object PSObject -Property @{Field="AccessFlags"; Alias="Access Flags"}
    new-object PSObject -Property @{Field="AuthAnonymous"; Alias="Auth Anonymous"}
)
$props = Get-SelectPropertyArray2 $propsToSelect
```

over this:

```powershell
$props = @(
    "Name"
    @{Expression="AccessFlags"; Name="Access Flags"}
    @{Expression="AuthAnonymous"; Name="Auth Anonymous"}
)
```

?

Comment: Did you forget some commas in the array literals?

Comment: @MikeShepard No. Only array literal in my answer is `,[PSObject]"Name"` and comma is here. Array expression `@()` free to contain as many statements as you want, and PowerShell allows to omit statement separator `;` at the end of line.

Comment: I haven't ever seen @() used without commas.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: The benefits of using the Get-SelectPropertyArraySet is i can specify either a string without an alias, the alias or an alias plus a block and it is all wrapped into one common format the Name/Expression script block.

Comment: Here are some examples:

$propsToSelect = @("AppPoolID")
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "autoStart" "AppPoolAutoStart"
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "processModel_idleTimeout" { $_.processModel.idleTimeout }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Handlers_AccessFlags" {
$flagValue = (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/handlers -Name AccessPolicy -PSPath $PSPath) 
if ($flagValue.GetType().Name -eq "ConfigurationAttribute")
{ "" } else {$flagValue}
}

sorry about the formatting

Comment: @Justin Same can be done without `Get-SelectPropertyArraySet`: $props="Just Property Name",@{Expression="Property Name";Name="And Alias"},@{Name="Alias";Expression={And Expression Script Block}}

Answer (score 1):

General workarround for this:

`<object> | Select-Object -Property ([String[]](<array>))`

Example:

`$config = Get-Item $PSPath | Select -Property ( [String[]]$props )`